# css for avoid scrolling

Tags: html, css

I want to avoid horizontal scrolling and leave some space above from menus. 
In my page I got some unwanted horizontal scrolling.I want to avoid it and want to add some space where I marked as red.I have created jsfiddle.and attached layout http://jsfiddle.net/mount/m5upe9r6/1/
[image]

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  font: normal 12px/1.5em"Liberation sans", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
html {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
div {
  width: 100%;
}
.header {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 150px;
  background: #1e5799;
  /* Old browsers */
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, #1e5799 0%, #2989d8 40%, #1e5799 100%, #7db9e8 100%);
  /* FF3.6+ */
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, color-stop(0%, #1e5799), color-stop(40%, #2989d8), color-stop(100%, #1e5799), color-stop(100%, #7db9e8));
  /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #1e5799 0%, #2989d8 40%, #1e5799 100%, #7db9e8 100%);
  /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
  background: -o-linear-gradient(left, #1e5799 0%, #2989d8 40%, #1e5799 100%, #7db9e8 100%);
  /* Opera 11.10+ */
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(left, #1e5799 0%, #2989d8 40%, #1e5799 100%, #7db9e8 100%);
  /* IE10+ */
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #1e5799 0%, #2989d8 40%, #1e5799 100%, #7db9e8 100%);
  /* W3C */
  filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#1e5799', endColorstr='#7db9e8', GradientType=1);
  /* IE6-9 */
}
.login {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0px 0px 0 0;
  text-align: right;
  width: 40%;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
.ribbon {
  background-color: #F70D1A;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  /* top left corner */
  position: absolute;
  left: -625px;
  top: 40px;
  /* 45 deg ccw rotation */
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  /* shadow */
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 10px #888;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 10px #888;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px #888;
}
.ribbon a {
  border: 1px solid #faa;
  color: #fff;
  display: block;
  font: bold 105.25%'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  margin: 1px 0;
  padding: 10px 50px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  /* shadow */
  text-shadow: 0 0 5px #444;
}
.logo {
  margin: 0px 0;
  padding: 15px 0px 0px 130px;
  cursor: pointer;
  float: left;
}
.topmenu {
  padding: 25px, 0px, 0px, 0px;
}
.topmenu ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 25px, 0px, 0px, 0px;
  text-align: center;
}
.topmenu ul li {
  display: inline;
}
.topmenu ul li a {
  display: inline;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 22px 16px;
  font-size: 15px;
  line-height: 17px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #0000A0;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
}
.topmenu ul li.active a,
.topmenu ul li a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: ;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="header">
    <div class="ribbon">
      <a href="#">BETA</a>
    </div>
    <!--end of robbon div -->

    <div class="logo" class="unselectable">
      <img src="image/DZB.png" style="width:220px;height:120px" alt="logo">
    </div>
    <!--end of logo div -->

    <div class="login">
      <button name="login" class="add">Login</button>
      <button name="Enquiry" class="upload">Enquiry</button>
    </div>
    <!--end of login div  -->

  </div>
  <!-- end of header div -->
  <div class="topmenu">
    <ul>
      <li><a>Product</a>
      </li>
      <li><a>Contuct us</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <!--end of Top menu div    -->

  <div class="slide">

  </div>
  <!-- end of slide div -->

</div>
<!-- end of main div  -->
```

Comment: Can your provide a link to website or past your example code?

Comment: Maybe just need to set ovewrflow but it's hard to tell for sure without a example or snipet

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> overflow-y: scroll;
> overflow-x: hidden;
> ```

Maybe this could resolve your problem ?

Comment: @user3386779 To your body class for example. But I wouldn't recommend this answer in your case. In fact this rule just crops the entire page, but in your example there is just a basic CSS mistake.

Comment: You can add this in your css file in your body class --> body { overflow-y: scroll; overflow-x: hidden; }
About the more space you want, your should add it in your css file :
.topmenu { margin: 25px auto 0 auto; }

Answer (score 1):

```
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  font: normal 12px/1.5em"Liberation sans", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
```

this is a good code to avoid scrolling but some time it can create scrolling issue , if u have any overflow element inside body . so , make sure to add

```
overflow-x: hidden;
```

hope , this make sense

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your CSS.

Changing your .logo padding to:
`padding: 15px 0px 0px 0px;` should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is target all div
**Remove this style**
div {width: 100%;}